# Dart: Storing arguments in a variable before passing

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, parameter-passing

For purposes of testing, it's useful to be able to "prepare" arguments to a function before executing such that the arguments can be checked against any result.

In JavaScript I can do this:

```js
function testFunc ({id, count}) {
  /* perform some operation */
  return {id, count}
}

const args = {
  id: 'someId',
  count: Math.round(Math.random() * 10),
}

const res = testFunc({...args})

/* check that count is correct etc */
```

How do I achieve the same flexibility in Dart?

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> testFunc({String id, int count}) {
  /* perform some operation */
  return {
    'id': id,
    'count': count,
  };
}

final args = /* erm? */

testFunc(args); /* hmmm? */
```

Am I trying to push the limits of a strongly typed language?

Answer (score 0):

Dart is a statically checked language.
Using a value with an unknown run-time structure, like a map, as parameters makes it impossible to statically check the validity of the arguments.

Take the example:

```
var data = {#name: "hello", #age: 18}; 
Person(...data)
```

(Using symbols for referring to source names, same as `Function.apply` and `noSuchMethod`).

Here it looks easy to see that the map actually has a `#name` and an `#age` entry, but that's because the map is written as a literal right next to the application. That's the one situation where you don't actually need spread arguments, because you could just write the arguments directly.

In all actually useful cases, it's not possible to see statically which entries the map has, and which types the values are for each key. The type of the map, `Map<Symbol, dynamic>` is not strong enough to allow checking the call. You should just use `Function.apply(Person, [], data)` ... except that we (still) do not allow constructors as functions (#216).

If Dart had typed structs/named tuples, it might be possible to do:

```
// Static type is the named tuple type `(String name, int age)`
var data = (name: "name", age: 18);
var person = Person(...data);
```

At this point, the static type of `data` is specific enough to allow the call to be checked statically.

also this is [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/893) in GitHub which I take the answer from